# C# P/Invoke on CUDA DLL eventually causes AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pinvoke, cuda, dllimport, access-violation

This is driving me crazy. I've looked all over, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what's causing this error.

I'm making a call to a DLL (that I've coded as a separate project) which runs a CUDA kernel on some data I'm using. Although, I suspect the issue isn't being caused by CUDA, since the code has been tested and works at least once, and usually 64-100 times before causing an AccessViolationException.

The issue is, I'm passing in three public static arrays:

```
public static float[] neuronInputs;
public static float[] connectionOutputs;
public static int[] calcOrder;
```

The data from neuronInputs gets copied onto the GPU, operated on, then copied back to connectionOutputs (calcOrder is only read, but not written). I perform a bunch of operations using the connectionOutputs array. Then I write over the neuronInputs array, and send it back to the GPU. Repeating until it fails. And it always fails.

I'm calling this function:

```
[DllImport("CUDANeural.dll")] 
 static extern void GenerateSubstrateConnections(
 [In, Out]    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]  float[] neuronInputs,
 [In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] calcOrder,
 [In, Out]      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] float[] outWeights
    );
```

I only allocate the memory for the three arrays once, and I allocate a large chunk for each. I've tested it on the managed side, and there is no way I would be indexing outside of the arrays inside the CUDA code.

I guess my question is, what is causing this AccessViolationException? Assuming it isn't the CUDA code.

EDIT:
Here's the call from the unmanaged side

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GenerateSubstrateConnections(
float* neuronInputs, int* calcOrder, float* outWeights);
```

It seems I might have been wrong about the CUDA side of programming. I've added in an cudaExitThread() call at the end of my call to the GenerateSubstrateConnections and this has seemed to correct the issue. However, for clarification, I'm calling a different function:

```
[DllImport("CUDANeural.dll")]
static extern void DebugSubstrateConnections(
[In, Out]     IntPtr neuronInputs,
[In, Out]  IntPtr calcOrder,
[In, Out]      IntPtr outWeights
);
```

And before I call GenerateSubstrateConnections in managed code I pin the GCHandles

```
 SubstrateDescription.inputHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(SubstrateDescription.neuronInputs, GCHandleType.Pinned);
 SubstrateDescription.connectionHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(SubstrateDescription.outputConnections, GCHandleType.Pinned);
calcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(calcOrder, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Then call

```
GenerateSubstrateConnections(
SubstrateDescription.inputHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
calcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
SubstrateDescription.connectionHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is necessary, but I know that it works (currently). Thank you for all the comments, they helped me squeeze out the issue.

Comment: The declaration looks fine, provided that it matches the C function signature. All I can tell is that the AccessViolationException is not caused by the C# declarations. So the cause must be somewhere else; most likely in the C code, maybe in the C# code. The only real way to debug this is to review the entire code, both on the managed and the unmanaged side.

Comment: If you've already ruled out the managed code and the CUDA code, then the only possibility is in the marshaling.  Can you show us the C function prototype for GenerateSubstrateConnections()?  Also, have you tested just calling that function multiple times with the same neuronInputs array (i.e. not overwriting the values)?  Does it still crash?

Comment: Maybe the unmanaged code keeps a pointer to managed memory for some reason, and the GC moves the managed arrays around between P/Invoke calls. Then the old memory locations would be invalid, leading to an AccessViolationException.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to allocate the arrays? I assume you're using the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` method, right?

Comment: @Mark H: Looking at his set of declarations, the arrays appear be regular .NET arrays, i.e. they are allocated in managed code. The marshaller will pin them for each P/Invoke call (but not between).

Comment: So the truth of the matter is that I blamed C# when I should have blamed my poor CUDA skillz (or lack thereof). In reality, it was actually a little of both, and I hadn't realized that some of the memory that I set (I copied the address of an int array from managed to unmanaged code) had been picked up by the GC and I was reading garbage numbers. This caused me to access memory in a kernel call that I shouldn't have, which then caused the AccessViolationException. Moral of the story, be careful what you copy from managed to unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a thread safety issue.  Since you are using static memory, you should be locking the object, or using some other synchronization option unless you are absolutely sure that it is single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure even you can do a simple pInvoke on CUDA Functions as they are not running on the main processor. Best option to directly use native CUDA API might be to use C++/CLI. And nVidia just released a support package for that.
Other simpler options include using OPENCL which has the .Net library available called [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) which provides Managed wrappers for most uses.

Comment: CUDA is just an extension of C (with support for some C++ functionality), and can definitely be called from pInvoke. I only know this because it worked, haha! So at least it's a proof of concept. If I was using C++ or C and calling CUDA, you could still say that the code isn't running on the main processor. What's the difference between calling code from C# that runs C code that calls CUDA, and calling the C code directly that runs CUDA? I wouldn't know the technical answer, but I guess philosophically, I believe they're the same.